# Saving line-break on localstorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage, line-breaks

So Im trying to make a simple sticky-note thingy using localstorage where you can type and its saves automatically.

I get a problem when ever I press linebreak. Localstorage doesn't apply the line break.

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="s_content">Type something, press linebreak and type something again. Then refresh</div>​
```

JS:

```
$('div.s_content').text(localStorage.getItem ("foo"))

$("div.s_content").on("keyup paste", function () {
localStorage.setItem ("foo", $('div.s_content').text())
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z2e6Y/

Try to type something, press return and type something more. Then refresh the page.

How can I apply the `<br>` / `line-break` onto localstorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change both of your .text() calls to .html() and it should work:

```
$('div.s_content').html(localStorage.getItem ("foo"))

$("div.s_content").on("keyup paste", function () {
   localStorage.setItem ("foo", $('div.s_content').html());
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k4dWX/3/

Since you are using is a tag, the data inside is HTML and not just text. So you need to set the content of div.s_content to HTML with br or div tags, rather than just line breaks.  If you are pulling the text from somewhere else, you need to convert linebreaks to br or div tags first.

Comment: Why didnt I thought of that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i thing i got ur question,

Ur saving data in Ajax call,

pass value like this,

```
if u use 
    $('#container').html(); // You ll get html tags with text
    //like this-----------> teste<br><br><br>r
else
    $('#container').text(); //  You ll get only  text
    //like this -----------> tester

try console and check buddy,

console.log('----------->'+$('#container').html());
console.log('----------->'+$('#container').text());


Your coding:

$('div.s_content').text(localStorage.getItem ("foo"))


$("div.s_content").on("keyup paste", function () {
    localStorage.setItem ("foo", $('div.s_content').html()) // changes has to Here text to html
});
```

Comment: That is the answer. As slolife answered quicker with the same answer I chose his as the correct. Thanks